# Google Slide API - creating a PIE Shape to a Google slide using the API and setting the start and end angles?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm looking to automate the creation of a google slide deck and I'd like to add a single pie slice shape to a given slide, and vary the start and end angle based off some underlying data.

I can use the Javascript (App Script) API to create presentations, add slides and add shapes and text to slides at the right position, but can't seem to find a way to set the start and end angle for a given slice (shapeType=PIE) like I can if I draw this manually on a google slide.

I've tried to create a few slices manually on a page with different angles, then read in the shape values using the App Script API, but there doesn't seem anything returned on the object property tree other than the usual standard [transform], [shape], [size] and objectId property sections, and these don't include a start/end angle property.

Is this possible and has anyone managed to do this?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

As of now, only Google Charts API has the objects to set start and end angles for pie charts.

From [Google Charts Documentation:](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

### Rotating a Pie Chart

By default, pie charts begin with the left edge of the first slice pointing straight up. You can change that with the pieStartAngle option.

Here, we rotate the chart clockwise 100 degrees with an option of pieStartAngle: 100. (So chosen because that particular angle happens to make the "Italian" label fit inside the slice.)

```
      var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        pieSliceText: 'label',
        title: 'Swiss Language Use (100 degree rotation)',
        pieStartAngle: 100,
      };
```

However this API is documented to be used only for web pages or Google Sites, there is no guarantee of this API working along Google Slides.

Alternatively, you can create a feature request to add rotation properties to shape objects in Google Slides natively:

[Submit ideas for Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en)